# Как поэтапно происходит SSH-аутентификация?

Tags: linux, ssh

1. Сгенерировал RSA-ключи (`ssh-keygen`).
2. Публичный ключ добавил на удалённый сервер (`ssh-copy-id`).

---

### Итого

1. У нас локально есть два ключа: `key`, `key.pub`; и запись в `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.
2. На удалённом сервере запись публичного ключа добавлена в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

Как поэтапно происходит процесс аутентификации: кто-что-кому отправляет и кто-что-как проверяет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

коротко и выборочно, касаясь только упомянутых файлов:

1. сервер **сообщает** клиенту свой публичный rsa-ключ (`/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`)
2. клиент **сверяет** его с соответствующей строкой в `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
3. клиент **сообщает** серверу используемый публичный ключ `key.pub` (впрочем, если этот файл отсутствует, то всё необходимое можно извлечь из файла `key` — см. ниже)
4. сервер **сверяет** его последовательно со всеми строками в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

примечание.

> У нас локально есть два ключа: `key`, `key.pub`

судя по названиям файлов, речь про один rsa-ключ, а не про два.

во втором файле, действительно, хранится только пара `{e,n}` (используя терминологию из [примера в википедийной статье про rsa](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80)), а в первом, вообще-то, хранятся и `e`, и `n`, и `d`, т.е., формально говоря, не только секретный ключ, но и публичный в том числе. потому файл `key.pub` и легко восстановить, имея лишь файл `key`, а хранится пара `{e,n}` в отдельном файле, насколько я понимаю, лишь для удобства пользователя.

---

для иллюстрации, вот составные части файла `key`:

```
$ openssl rsa -in key -text -noout | sed '/^ /d'
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
prime1:
prime2:
exponent1:
exponent2:
coefficient:
```

а вот составные части файла `key.pub` (ну, только сохранённого под именем `key.pem` в формате, понятном программе *openssl*):

```
$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -pubin -noout | sed '/^ /d'
Public-Key: (2048 bit)
Modulus:
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

видно, что в файле `key.pub`, как и «полагается» для публичного ключа, присутствует два компонента: `e` (`exponent`) и `n` (`modulus`).

а в файле `key`, как в греции, «есть всё»: не только пара `n` (`modulus`) и `d` (насколько я понимаю различие в терминологии, это `privateexponent`), но и тот же `e` (`publicexponent`), и много чего другого.

Comment: Да, `речь про один rsa-ключ`. У меня как раз и возник вопрос об этом процессе, так как я заметил, что отсутствие `key.pub` файла на клиенте никак не влияет на соединение (из-за непонимания процесса, казалось что он нужен обязательно). Получается, на 3-ем этапе публичный ключ берётся из приватного ключа?.. В `~/.ssh/config` у меня для удалённого хоста прописан `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key`.

Comment: да, в файле с секретной частью ключа (ну, так его принято называть, хотя, как видите, название не совсем соответствует сути) содержится (в том числе) и всё, что содержится в файле с публичной частью. я это проиллюстрировал специально. а откуда именно брать пару `{e,n}` — в общем, и не существенно.