# SSL шфирование публичным ключом

Tags: алгоритм, ssh, ssl, криптография, шифрование

Почему если зашифровать данные публичным ключом , я не могу их дешифровать тем же ключом? Какая фишка в алгоритме, что дешифрация стает невозможной и дешифровать можно только приватным ключом?

Comment: Погуглите алгоритм работы RSA, в интернете вроде есть много наглядных объяснений с математикой

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Comment: уточню, что rsa — это всего лишь один из алгоритмов, реализующих [ассиметричное шифрование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC). вот про ассиметричное шифрование, собственно, и надо читать.

Answer (score 1):

> Какая фишка в алгоритме, что дешифрация стает невозможной и дешифровать можно только приватным ключом?

существуют две схемы шифрования: [симметричная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) и [асимметричная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC).

при симметричном шифровании для шифрации и дешифрации используется один и тот же ключ.

при ассиметричном шифровании используется взаимосвязанная пара ключей — секретный и публичный. сообщение, зашифрованное секретным ключом, можно расшифровать только публичным, и наоборот, зашифрованное публичным ключом можно расшифровать только секретным.

публичный ключ, как явствует из названия, может быть доступен публично. его «утечка» при передаче респонденту (в отличие от симметричной схемы шифрования) не влечёт за собой никаких негативных последствий. ну а передача секретного ключа не только излишня, но и противопоказана.

типичные примеры использования ассиметричного шифрования:

1. подтверждение авторства сообщения: обладая публичным ключом, вы можете быть уверены, что полученное вами зашифрованное сообщение отправлено именно обладателем соответствующего секретного ключа.
2. сообщение может прочитать только адресат: зашифровав сообщение публичным ключом, вы можете быть уверены, что расшифровать его сможет только обладатель соответствующего секретного ключа.
3. комбинация предыдущих — обмен шифрованными сообщениями: шифруя сообщения своим секретным ключом и публичным ключом респондента, вы с респондентом можете быть взаимно уверены и в авторстве сообщений, и в том, что никто третий не сможет их прочитать.

Comment: По-моему данный текст никак не отвечает на вопрос «почему». А чтобы ответить на него, нужно в математику погружаться

Comment: да, это ответ большей частью на второй из заданных вопросов. ну а математическая часть изложена по второй из приведённых мною ссылок.

Comment: @andreymal, если вдруг надумаете писать ответ про математичесий аппарат, можете невозбранно воспользоваться примером из [другого моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629682/178576), который (пример) слегка способствует наведению мостов между матабстракциями и реальными байтиками внутри файлов.