# ssh2_auth_pubkey_file Unable to open public key file

Tags: php, ssh

Пытаюсь из php подключиться по ssh.
Через терминал подключаюсь с использованием файлов ключей без проблем.
Из php подключиться не получается.
Мой код:

```
$sshConnection = ssh2_connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', xxx); // вызов данной функции успешен
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($sshConnection, 'root', 'keys/public.pub', 'keys/private');
```

Вызов ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() возвращает ошибку:

```
Warning: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for umicms using public key: Unable to open public key file
```

Файлы ключей хранятся локально.
Пути указаны верно, через file_get_contents() можно их посмотреть.
Формат public-ключа следующий:

```
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAxWKGsPt+LqwxHW0++XcbLeIxyqsoJK5MZv6h
DxDiEMLDM9lX2vX+Izyz3kakxXS37N8jutWRVHsTocMsP5uofI1E9ZlB2UgRx12F
BAEk+E6cuHtbsKzDO86j7SFfxU1ymYI4mgidYaBNvPTirqjVvzOSQ8sXUTIxdWes
ES+Nqjbqb7++yvOm4D2jyrNmdEmYuDRchLpqQq64+UMPjsknNnUw3UBVDBNsZdNi
6xSQDIxZEesrHH5CjatbNi5CDmwZu+XQEfaDoIJCb1FIoTo7NMs2rivEcoz6Okr4
pMpYVJa23/QNsX25h1ugTcCJoQrCecA0L0x4aD+sVNcPU98wzw==
```

Отсюда возникает 2 вопроса:

1. Собственно, как побороть ошибку?
2. Где должен располагаться public-ключ, можно ли его хранить локально, или нужно обязательно указывать адрес на сервере, к которому подключаюсь? (таким способом кстати тоже не работает, вылетает ошибка "Unable to open public key file")

Answer (score 0):

1. вообще публичная часть ключа для осуществления соединения по протоколу *ssh* не нужна: [обе составляющие публичного ключа содержатся и внутри секретного ключа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629682/178576). зачем путь к публичному ключу передавать как обязательный параметр — оставим на совести разработчика этой функции.
2. файлы с публичной (раз уж её так хочет разработчик) и секретной частью ключа должны располагаться на той же машине, где вы и запускаете процесс *php*. и, естественно, эти файлы должны быть доступны для чтения пользователю, от имени которого выполняется процесс *php*.
3. путь к файлам лучше сразу указать абсолютный, так как текущий каталог (от которого «отсчитывается» относительный путь) у вас в процессе разработки (или при развёртке/переносе сайта) может и поменяться. впрочем, если в пути к файлам присутствует путь к домашнему каталогу пользователя, от имени которого выполняется процесс *php*, то, думаю, имеет смысл брать эту часть из переменной окружения `HOME`.
4. на всякий случай дополню базовыми требованиями (это уже со стороны *libssh*): весь каталог `~/.ssh` (и секретная часть ключа в особенности) должны быть доступны для чтения только владельцу. и именно ему и принадлежать.

Comment: Ответа "по сути" я не увидел. В вопросе я описал, что размещал файлы ключей на машине, на которой запущен php процесс и файлы доступны для чтения.

Comment: 1. в примере у вас указан относительный путь. 2. на два заданных вопроса (*Где должен располагаться public-ключ, можно ли его хранить локально, или нужно обязательно указывать адрес на сервере, к которому подключаюсь?*) я дал, надеюсь, вполне исчерпывающий ответ. 3. на третий вопрос (*как побороть ошибку?*) ответ в общем-то довольно очевиден: надо соблюсти все требования. я вот проверил на машине, где завалялся php, и файл вполне себе находится. ну правда, само подключение не происходит из-за [ошибки](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78661), но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: ах, да, на всякий случай озвучу ещё одно, базовое требование к секретным ключам: они должны быть доступны для чтения только владельцу.